# Build a realistic tree with the three.js library only

Tags: graphics, 3d, three.js

I would like to know if there exists a possibility to compose realistic trees by using only the `three.js` library or I'm forced to import an existing model of a tree in my application?

Comment: http://www.snappytree.com/

Comment: There's no reason why you wouldn't be able to use any one of the existing algorithms or libraries for generating the tree geometry/mesh and passing it to Three.js. If you're asking if Three.js has a method for doing it automatically, then no -- you'll need to find a library or roll your own. Btw I believe snappytree is based on [proctree](https://github.com/supereggbert/proctree.js/). There is also [this Three.js example](http://inear.se/three_tree/)